# Finding a substring from a database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Database like this"

```
NAME - AGE
alex - 20
mathew - 14
alexandra-31
human-10
```

now in a text box elsewhere when i type say "al",I should get the result as alex and alexandra.

how do i do this in MySQL? please help.

Comment: [mySQL manual: String comparison functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks alot fellow developers

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from tableName
where name like 'al%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select name, age
From yourtable
Where name like 'al%'
```

Or, if you want to type any part of the name:

```
Select name, age
From yourtable
Where name like '%le%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table your_table
(NAME varchar(50),AGE int);

insert into your_table (NAME,AGE) values ('alex',20);
insert into your_table (NAME,AGE) values ('mathew',14);
insert into your_table (NAME,AGE) values ('alexandra',31);
insert into your_table (NAME,AGE) values ('human',10);

select NAME from your_table where name like 'al%';
```

Should do the trick...

Comment: Based on your answer, I think you should complete your LIKE - statement. In my eyes use: ... like '%al%'

Comment: Fair enough. I guess it depends on what the guy wants to come back in his text box. If you completed the LIKE statement with '%al%' then names such as 'hal' and 'malcolm' would come back when entering 'al' as well as 'alex' and 'alexandra' instead of just 'alex' and 'alexandra'. Thanks for the comment though!